# mySQL Parent, children model and default values

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have a database that handles images and albums and album categories.

One album can have multiple albums (subalbums) and it's only 1 level deep.

One album is categorized in only one album category.

Did some research here and i believe the most appropriate database model is this one

```
album_category (album_category_id, name, description, position)

album (
    album_id,
    album_category_id,
    parent_album_id,
    name,
    description,
    cover_filename,
    position
)
```

[image]

I did a couple of things that i'm not sure of. I need your expertise.

1. When an album `parent_album_id` is empty (meaning it's not a subalbum), the default value is zero. Is that ok? I have the option of checking `Allow NULL` and make it default null. Is that a better solution?
2. If the album is a subalbum, the `parent_album_id` is set to a valid `album_id`. But, what do i do with the `album_category_id` for a subalbum? Do i set it to null or 0? Do i set it to the `album_category_id` referenced by the `parent_album_id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your 1st question, I would prefer 0 over null because you don't have to setup special handling for the null. Since album_id is auto increment, a valid album_id will never be zero.

For your 2nd question, The beauty of having a category id for the sub-album is that you can set it to a different category if that is the case. I would default to the same category, or null. Null would be a "special case", meaning that it uses the parent's category. If null, in your query you could get the category from it's parent, and that way if the parent category changes, so do the sub-albums' category, without having to update any sub-albums when updating the parent.

Comment: making the album_category_id null for the subalbum makes a lot of sense, for all the reasons you've mentioned. thanks

Answer (score 1):

For your first question, either one could work. But zero only works when a valid parent_album_id can not be zero.

For the second question, I think you have to figure out which category the album is in. album_category_id is not related to album_id nor parent_album_id, unless you decide to connect them.